# What is JINN project?

Tags: legacy-protocol, ternary, jinn, ternary-hardware

I would like to know more about the `JINN` project.

- What is `JINN`?
- Why is it important to `Iota`?
- Where can I get more information about `JINN`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy protocol and given the latest updates it might make sense to only keep recent Shimmer, ShimmerEVM and IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the JINN website: http://iotanodes.org/jinn/

Nobody knows much about Jinn project except its global scope. 
The idea is to develop a low energy ternary processor.
Everything else remains secret.

It's important for IOTA because IOTA uses ternary to compute hashes and so all computation to sign transactions involves ternary operations, which are not optimal on binary processors.

It's important because a "**low-energy**-processor" is particularly adapted to IOT devices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am an amateur student of cryptography, but I am involved with microelectronics and nanotechnology. Hardware is something that interests me a lot. +1

Answer (score 5):

JINN is currently under NDA and doesn't release any information about its development.

Here are some snippets of what we know about JINN via the developers on Slack:

- JINN is a low cost (target price: $1) ternary processor which is designed to have a small footprint to be put into any sort of device, including very low power, cheap, and small IoT devices in order to manage the PoW of IOTA and other unrevealed tasks
- Iota was designed after JINN was conceptualized and no other blockchain coins were able to suit the requirements for its usage
- The entire IOTA team works closely with whoever is developing JINN, with likely overlap between the two teams
- David has referred to "fog" and "mist" as a next generation version of the cloud, potentially referring to using JINN as the foundation for a future layer upon the internet of decentralized processing

More information about JINN will be released with time. For now, there is almost no public information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am an amateur student of cryptography, but I am involved with microelectronics and nanotechnology. Hardware is something that interests me a lot. +1